# How to recursively call a procedure when there is a deadlock?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have jobs "stored procedures" runs over night. Every now and then I run into a deadlock. I want to write a code that will execute the same procedure after 15 minutes up to 3 time if a deadlock is found.

Assume the time now is 10AM. Then run it at 10AM, if a deadlock found, call the job again at 10:15AM, then at 10:30AM "if dead locked", then 10:45AM "if dead locked." If the last run dead locked then terminate the job completely.

Here is What I have done.

```
DECLARE totalTrys INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
    @err_num = MYSQL_ERRNO;

    if(@err_num = 1213 AND totalTrys < 4) THEN
        SET totalTrys = totalTrys + 1;
        SELECT SLEEP(900);
        CALL guardi.prod_update_guardi_accounts();
    END IF;

END;
```

Is this a valid approach? is there a better way other than eliminating deadlocks all together?

Comment: you have to add a loop

Comment: what If I pass the totalTrys and a parameter to the procedure?

Comment: You could do that, however that part was not in view here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep everything in the procedure: Then all code related to this behaviour is at one location. Also: Would the deadlock not follow the execution of you CALL statement instead of proceed? If is proceeds, it is probably already solved, and we are then waiting for nothing. Also transactions following a deadlock, would just be executed after the deadlock is resolved.

My approach with your code would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE manageAccounts()
BEGIN
DECLARE totalTrys INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
@err_num = MYSQL_ERRNO;
CALL guardi.prod_update_guardi_accounts();
WHILE(@err_num = 1213 AND totalTrys < 4) DO
    SET totalTrys = totalTrys + 1;
    SELECT SLEEP(900);
    CALL guardi.prod_update_guardi_accounts();
END WHILE;
END;
```

You will have to test this: Untested, so typos are not impossible.